# Efficient way to calculate distances between every point and use the shorted few to calculate a value then add it back to the array.

Tags: python, arrays, csv, sorting

The task: Calculate a stat for each point using points that are the shortest distance away from the original point.

To do this i have created a text file for each point where i write the distance from every other point. Then I open the text file and use csv to sort the distance and use the shorted few to calculate a value and write it in a new text file.

Surely there must be a more efficient way of achieving this because i have thousands of points, this process seems awfully time-consuming.

Comment: You have to show what have you tried so far. Please post your code.

Comment: Hint: if you know that distance from A to B then you know the distance from B to A